# auditTrail yii extension

Tags: php, exception, yii, yii-modules

I am a newbie to yii and I am installing extension auditTrail.
 I have made all the required changes to my main.php config file but everytime it is showing the same error

```
'Alias "auditTrail.AuditTrailModule" is invalid. Make sure it points
 to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.'
```

Please help me out. thankyou in advance.. my editted file is here:

```
// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'My Web Application',

// preloading 'log' component
'preload'=>array('log'),

// autoloading model and component classes
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.modules.auditTrail.models.AuditTrail',


),

'modules'=>array(


    'auditTrail'=>array(),
    // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>false,
        // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),

),

// application components
'components'=>array(
    'user'=>array(
        // enable cookie-based authentication
        'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
    ),
    // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
    ),
    // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

    'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=assetdb',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'Preksha#12',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),

    'errorHandler'=>array(
        // use 'site/error' action to display errors
        'errorAction'=>'site/error',
    ),
    'log'=>array(
        'class'=>'CLogRouter',
        'routes'=>array(
            array(
                'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                'levels'=>'error, warning',
            ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
            array(
                'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
            ),
            */
        ),
    ),
),

// application-level parameters that can be accessed
// using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
'params'=>array(
    // this is used in contact page
    'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
),
);
```

here is the error ::

```
CException

Alias "auditTrail.AuditTrailModule" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.
```

Comment: Could you post a code sample of the problem so we can narrow down what you are having trouble with?

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from " http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/audittrail "  version 1.2.0  and followed the same instructions to edit config main.php n when i run in xampp it shows the above error

Comment: Check you directory has AuditTrailModule.php file  [link](http://postimg.org/image/n1uhm9lqr/)